# Reading Media Access Control (MAC) with Arduino

Tags: arduino, ethernet

Is it possible to read the Media Access Control string from an ethernet Arduino?  I would like to read it and use it as part of a hashing algorithm.

Comment: I can read the MAC code of my computer in Delphi (my current computer ethernet MAC is 00-24-1D-14-0A-DB) but I need to read the MAC code of an ethernet Arduino card.

Answer (score 0):

More than reading it, you should set it. From the [docs](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoEthernetShield/):

"The shield must be assigned a MAC address and a fixed IP address using the Ethernet.begin() function. A MAC address is a globally unique identifier for a particular device. Current **Ethernet shields come with a sticker indicating the MAC address you should use** with them."

I suppose you're using an Eth shield, but with [ethernet board](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardEthernet) it should be the same. You can use the **MAC address printed on the board** or a custom one, you're free to decide. Just don't use the same address for different boards:

```
byte mac[] = {  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
// start the Ethernet connection:
if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
  Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
  // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
  for(;;)
   ;
}
```

Comment: Well yes I see how that works.  But I need (want) to be able to read the MAC programmatically because there will be lots of the thing I am building and I don't want to have to install them individually.  
In windows there are op system functions that can be used to read the MAC of cards connected.  Is there anything like that in Arduino?

Comment: I really can't see your problem. If you define a byte array containing the MAC address you choose, reading it is a simple matter of scanning the array...If you have to read it "remotely", just define a function that returns the byte array